# Module 'algoliasearch' is not available Error

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, algolia

I am trying to create a Instant Search Prototype using Algolia [AngularJS module](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js#angularjs-module) . I am using an app generated via jhipster (Micro Service Gateway) which uses Angular JS v1.x.

However when I launch my app I get this error:
[image]

I ran the following commands to install algolia search js module

```
1. npm install algoliasearch --save
2. bower install algoliasearch -S
3. Added algoliasearch as a dependency in app.module.js
```

I also cross checked all relevant files (See Below) but couldnt find any problems. Other modules are loaded properly.

1. index.html : This has script tag for algoliasearch.js file which is present locally:
   [image]
2. bower.json has algoliasearch js client installed properly and I can see algoliasearch folder under bower_components
   [image]
3. Here is where I have added algoliasearch js module app.module.js
   [image]

Not sure if I have missed anything. Any help on resolving this issue would be great.

**Update 11/20:**
Thanks to the Answers here. I got this working by adding the following to my bower.json file

```
"algoliasearch": {
    "main":[
        "dist/algoliasearch.js",
        "dist/algoliasearch.angular.js"
     ],
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to JHipster: to get `algoliasearch.angular.js` automatically included you need to add it to your project's `bower.json` file like what we already do for other dependencies when their `bower.json` does not include enough files (too many) required in our context:

```
"overrides": {
    "algoliasearch ": {
      "main": [
        "dist/algoliasearch.js",
        "dist/algoliasearch.angular.js"
      ]
    },
```

Don't forget to run `gulp` or `gulp inject` after editing `bower.json` to inject these 2 scripts (see [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/development/#using-gulp) on recommended workflow to run both mvn/gradle and gulp)

No need to include minified versions of these files as they'll get minified by JHipster gulp build process.

Comment: Thank You. This did it. Although I also had to add angular as a dependency for algoliasearch as suggested by @sunil B N.

Comment: That's weird because if you did this and run either `gulp serve` or `gulp inject`, it should have inserted algoliasearch.angular.js as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include angular specific build something like

```
algoliasearch.angular.min.js
```

And also put script include of `angular.js` above this.